# Add count of duplicate observations to data frame

Tags: r, duplicates, dataset

I am trying to get all dupicated observations. I was looking but all solutions seems to give for columns. Is it possible get the entire rows?

My dataset looks like this

```
structure(list(CrimeId = c(160903280L, 160912272L, 160912590L, 
160912801L, 160912811L, 160913003L), OriginalCrimeTypeName = c("Assault / Battery", 
"Homeless Complaint", "Susp Info", "Report", "594", "Ref'd"), 
    OffenseDate = c("2016-03-30T00:00:00", "2016-03-31T00:00:00", 
    "2016-03-31T00:00:00", "2016-03-31T00:00:00", "2016-03-31T00:00:00", 
    "2016-03-31T00:00:00"), CallTime = c("18:42", "15:31", "16:49", 
    "17:38", "17:42", "18:29"), CallDateTime = c("2016-03-30T18:42:00", 
    "2016-03-31T15:31:00", "2016-03-31T16:49:00", "2016-03-31T17:38:00", 
    "2016-03-31T17:42:00", "2016-03-31T18:29:00"), Disposition = c("REP", 
    "GOA", "GOA", "GOA", "REP", "GOA"), Address = c("100 Block Of Chilton Av", 
    "2300 Block Of Market St", "2300 Block Of Market St", "500 Block Of 7th St", 
    "Beale St/bryant St", "16th St/pond St"), City = c("San Francisco", 
    "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", 
    "San Francisco"), State = c("CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", 
    "CA"), AgencyId = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), Range = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AddressType = c("Premise Address", "Premise Address", 
    "Premise Address", "Premise Address", "Intersection", "Intersection"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show your expected result?

Comment: I don't see any duplicates in the sample data. Also not sure what you want - do you want to get one copy of each duplicate? All copies of each duplicate? Something else?

Comment: (And also surprised about the "for columns"  comment. `duplicated()` works just fine on a whole data frame and considers the entire row.)

Comment: I looked for dupes when removing 1-column, 2-columns (all combinations), 3, and detected no duplicates. Finally with `combn(12, 4, FUN = function(z) any(duplicated(quux[-z])))` I found one (out of 495) combination of columns-removed where a duplicate exists. The hard thing about making good/reproducible questions on SO is that the sample data actually has to show (unambiguously) the symptom you're talking about. In this case, you need to be explicit about the columns of interest for this deduplication.

Comment: A quick Google search turned up this:
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Finding_and_removing_duplicate_records/

Is this what you are wanting?
When posting to Stack Overflow, it is helpful to give more context and details so others can know how to help.

Comment: the dataset is so much large. I want something to identify how many times a row appear exactly equal in the entire dataset. I mean, if I have row 1 and row 5 with the same record in all columns create a new column with number 2 which means there are 2 equal rows. rows 1 and 5 will have the number 2 in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` try `group_by_all` or the now recommended `group_by(across(everything()))` equivalent. Using a slightly extended data set where I created a duplicated entry (row 2 and 5).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(across(everything())) %>% 
  mutate(dup = n())
...AgencyId Range AddressType       dup
...  <chr>    <lgl> <chr>           <int>
...1 1        NA    Premise Address     1
...2 1        NA    Premise Address     2
...3 1        NA    Premise Address     1
...4 1        NA    Premise Address     1
...5 1        NA    Premise Address     2
...6 1        NA    Intersection        1
...7 1        NA    Intersection        1
```

(only showing the last 4 columns)

##### ext. data

```
df <- structure(list(CrimeId = c(160903280L, 160912272L, 160912590L,
160912801L, 160912272L, 160912811L, 160913003L), OriginalCrimeTypeName = c("Assault / Battery",
"Homeless Complaint", "Susp Info", "Report", "Homeless Complaint",
"594", "Ref'd"), OffenseDate = c("2016-03-30T00:00:00", "2016-03-31T00:00:00",
"2016-03-31T00:00:00", "2016-03-31T00:00:00", "2016-03-31T00:00:00",
"2016-03-31T00:00:00", "2016-03-31T00:00:00"), CallTime = c("18:42",
"15:31", "16:49", "17:38", "15:31", "17:42", "18:29"), CallDateTime = c("2016-03-30T18:42:00",
"2016-03-31T15:31:00", "2016-03-31T16:49:00", "2016-03-31T17:38:00",
"2016-03-31T15:31:00", "2016-03-31T17:42:00", "2016-03-31T18:29:00"
), Disposition = c("REP", "GOA", "GOA", "GOA", "GOA", "REP",
"GOA"), Address = c("100 Block Of Chilton Av", "2300 Block Of Market St",
"2300 Block Of Market St", "500 Block Of 7th St", "2300 Block Of Market St",
"Beale St/bryant St", "16th St/pond St"), City = c("San Francisco",
"San Francisco", "San Francisco", "San Francisco", "San Francisco",
"San Francisco", "San Francisco"), State = c("CA", "CA", "CA",
"CA", "CA", "CA", "CA"), AgencyId = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1",
"1", "1"), Range = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AddressType = c("Premise Address",
"Premise Address", "Premise Address", "Premise Address", "Premise Address",
"Intersection", "Intersection")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3",
"4", "21", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

With `library(dplyr)` you can do `your_data %>% add_count(across(everything()))` to add a count grouped by every column.

Demo:

```
mtcars[c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3), ] %>% 
  add_count(across(everything()))
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb n
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2
# 3 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2
# 4 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 3
# 5 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2
# 6 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 3
# 7 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 3
```